# How to manipulate the DOM of React.JS app in chrome browser and need to add a event listener for a specific button present in source code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, react-hooks, react-devtools

Is it possible to manipulate the DOM of react app especially the JavaScript functionality? I tried chrome extension React Dev Tools and able to change HTML content only and if the application is in UAT it is not working. I appreciate any suggestion regarding browser level manipulation of react app functionality.